# Spotify Web API Search Results

Tags: python, web-crawler, spotify, spotipy

If I use the search method to search for artists but instead of passing a name just a letter, will spotify return ALL artists who have that letter in their name or does it return only a portion of artists with the letter in their names?

Is it possible to be measuring this?

My need is to extract from the platform all singers that start with a specific letter, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a request to `/v1/search?q=t&type=artist` for example, then the API will return all artists containing the letter 'T'.

BUT in paginated form. For example, the response for the request would return:

`"limit": 20,
    "next": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=t&type=artist&offset=20&limit=20",
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total": 10000`

So you kniw, the total is 1000 artists (not sure if maybe 1000 is the max that Spotify will ever return for a search query), but renders 20 artists per page.

The maximum artists per page you can request is 50 items.

See https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/ for more information.

Comment: In short spotify won't give me all the data they have. Is there a way around this limitation to get all results? Or at least know how many results altogether would be the answer for me to compare with what I got?